# Magic Square in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, fault, magic-square

Yet another magic square problem. I'm creating an odd magic square program in C++, and for some reason the program keeps giving a segmentation fault error and quitting. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

#include <cstring>

using std::memset;

int *generateOddSquare(int n) {
    if (n % 2 != 0 && n >= 3) {
        int row = 0, col = n / 2, square = n * n;
        int **matrix = new int *[n], *dest = new int[square];

        memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix[0][0]) * square);

        for (int i = 1; i <= square; i++) {
            matrix[row][col] = i;

            if (i % n == 0)
                row++;
            else {
                if (row == 0)
                    row = n - 1;
                else
                    row--;

                if (col == (n - 1))
                    col = 0;
                else
                    col++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                dest[(i * n) + j] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        return dest;
    } else
        return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int *arr = generateOddSquare(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it? Is the way I'm declaring my pointers correct?

Comment: You haven't initialised the matrix row pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an array of pointers:

```
int **matrix = new int *[n]
```

but don't initialise those to point to anything; hence the segementation fault when you try to dereference them. If you really must juggle pointers, then allocate an array for each to point at:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    matrix[i] = new int[n];
}
```

and don't forget to delete all of these allocations, if you care about memory leaks.

Unless this is an exercise in masochism, use the standard library to make life easier:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(n, std::vector<int>(n));
```

and return `std::vector<int>` rather than `int*` to save the caller the hassle of juggling and deleting the pointer.

Comment: Ya, I did that, and then simply flattened the matrix and returned the vector's data, but that didn't end up working out well enough since I couldn't find a significant way to iterate over them. I fixed that though so I may switch back to them.

Answer (score 1):

You are only partially instantiating matrix.  You have `int **matrix = new int *[n]` which will give you your rows but you are defining the columns.  To completely initialize you need to use

```
int **matrix = new int *[n];
for (int i = 0; i < col_dimension; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[col_dimension];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing null pointers. You have a 2-d array:

```
int **matrix = new int *[n];
```

That you clear (incorrectly - size should be should be `n * sizeof(*matrix)`):

```
memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix[0][0]) * square);
```

And then immediately write into:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= square; i++) {
    matrix[row][col] = i;
    ....
}
```

But `matrix[0]` is `NULL`. You need to allocate all of the pointers first!

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    matrix[i] = new int[whatever];
}
```

Comment: Would `whatever` be `n`?

Comment: @T145 If it's supposed to be square, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

use vectors.

```
    vector<vector<int> > matrix(n, vector<int>(n, 0));
    OddMagicSquare(matrix, n, -1);



void OddMagicSquare(vector<vector<int>> &matrix, int n)
{
    auto nsqr = n * n;

    // start position
    auto row = rand() % n;
    auto col = rand() % n;
    auto start = 1;

    for (auto index = start; index <= nsqr + (start -1); ++index)
    {
        while (col >= n)
            col -= n;

        while (col < 0)
            col += n;

        while (row >= n)
            row -= n;

        while (row < 0)
            row += n;

        matrix[row][col] = index;

        row--;
        col++;

        if (index%n == 0)
        {
            row += 2;
            --col;
        }
    }
}
```